# Azure SQL database clone problems

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to clone Azure SQL database on same Azure SQL server but there is some problems. I don't have any clue what is causing problem.

```
$SubscriptionId = "**********"
$SourceResourceGroupName = "rg"
$SourceServerName = "sql"
$SourceDatabaseName = "sql_test"

$TargetResourceGroupName = "rg"
$TargetServerName = "sql"
$TargetDatabaseName = "sql_dev"

$UserName = "*****"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "**********" –AsPlainText -Force

$Timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm"
$DatabaseToBackup = $SourceDatabaseName
$StorageUri = "**********"
$BackupDestination = $StorageUri + $DatabaseToBackup + "_" + $Timestamp + ".bacpac"
$StorageAccountName = "**********"

Set-AzContext -Subscription $SubscriptionId

$StorageKey = "**************"

Write-Host $BackupDestination

$export=New-AzSqlDatabaseExport `
    -ResourceGroupName $SourceResourceGroupName `
    -ServerName $SourceServerName `
    -DatabaseName $DatabaseToBackup `
    -UseNetworkIsolation $true `
    -SqlServerResourceIdForPrivateLink "********" `
    -AuthenticationType AdPassword `
    -AdministratorLogin $Username `
    -AdministratorLoginPassword $Password `
    -StorageKeyType StorageAccessKey `
    -StorageUri $BackupDestination `
    -StorageKey $StorageKey `
    -StorageAccountResourceIdForPrivateLink "*******"


$exportstatus = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $export.OperationStatusLink
while ($exportstatus.Status -eq "InProgress") {
    Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $export.OperationStatusLink
    $exportstatus = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $export.OperationStatusLink
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
}
```

This is first time when I'm seeing this kind error

Error code:

```
New-AzSqlDatabaseExport : An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: '************'
At line:25 char:9
+ $export=New-AzSqlDatabaseExport `
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzSqlDatabaseExport], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ImportExport.Cmdlet.NewAzureSqlDatabaseExport
 
Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'OperationStatusLink' because it is null.
At line:40 char:74
+ ... seImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $export.OperationStatusLink
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ImportExport.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus
```

Any ideas what I have to change. I have struggled with this problem now couple days and it is very hard to find answers to problem. Running out of ideas :)

Comment: Try adding the `-debug` parameter to the `New-AzSqlDatabaseExport` (this is where the `CloudException` is thrown. You should then be able to see the contents of the `CloudException` error, which should reveal more detail (e.g. [Error when calling New-AzSqlDatabaseExport with UseNetworkIsolation on $true · Issue #13964 · Azure/azure-powershell · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13964))

Comment: I'm getting response:

error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by increasing the size of Target Database.

You can increase the size of your Target Database using below command.

```
-DatabaseMaxSizeBytes “DB_Size_in_bytes”
```

Comment: Thanks! So where I need to add this?